# Converting a nested array into a set of magic methods

Tags: php, arrays, getter-setter

I am experimenting with the magic method `__call` and decided to do such a thing as converting a nested array into something similar to a collection. The key of the nested array is the collection method. At the end of each chain, the `get()` method is used to return the result as an array.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class ArrayCollection
{
    private const GET_LAST_ITEM = 'get';
    private const SINGLE_KEY = '_';

    protected array $data = [];

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * @return self|array
     */
    public function __call(string $name, array $args)
    {
        if ($name === self::GET_LAST_ITEM) {
            return array_key_exists(self::SINGLE_KEY, $this->data)
                ? array_pop($this->data)
                : $this->data;
        }

        $offset = array_shift($args);
        $current = $this->data[$name] ?? null;

        $this->data = is_array($current)
            ? $current[$offset] ?? $current
            : (
                is_string($current) || is_int($current)
                    ? [self::SINGLE_KEY => $current]
                    : $this->data
            );

        return $this;
    }
}

$collection = (new ArrayCollection(
    [
        'a' => [
            'nested' => [
                ['item' => 100],
                ['item' => 200],
                ['item' => 300],
                ['children' => [
                    'first' => 325,
                    'last' => [350, 375]
                ]]
            ]
        ],
        'b' => [
            'nested' => [
                ['item' => 400],
                ['item' => 500],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'xp' => PHP_INT_MAX
            ]
        ]
    ]
));

print_r($collection->b()->nested(1)->item()->get());
```

And everything works as it should, if I make only one call, since the key array is changing, there will be no correct result on the second call. Example

```
print_r($collection->b()->children()->xp()->get());
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 350
    [1] => 375
)
*/
print_r($collection->b()->children()->xp()->get());
/*
Array
(
)
*/
```

I want to get the same result for multiple calls. Can anyone tell me if I can somehow get around this approach? Thanks.

Comment: Use __copy__ of `this->data`.

Comment: @u_mulder, thanks, but I don't fully understand where to use copying, could you please show an example? Do you mean to use `clone`?

Comment: You are always changing your $this->data after calling b() method. So if you call it again there is no b key in your array. You could just returning copy of $this (clone), not $this in return statement.

Comment: @LordF , @u_mulder ,  thanks to everyone, solved with `clone $this`;

Comment: We do not resolve questions via comment.  Please either: self-delete this question, close this question with a suitable duplicate (if you can find one), or post an educational answer then accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commentators, the solution turned out to be simple, it was necessary to return a clone of the `$this` object in the method.

```
public function __call(string $name, array $args)
{
    if ($name === self::GET_LAST_ITEM) {
        return array_key_exists(self::SINGLE_KEY, $this->data)
            ? array_pop($this->data)
            : $this->data;
    }

    $offset = array_shift($args);
    $current = $this->data[$name] ?? null;

    $this->data = is_array($current)
        ? $current[$offset] ?? $current
        : (
            is_string($current) || is_int($current)
                ? [self::SINGLE_KEY => $current]
                : $this->data
        );

    return clone $this; // <<< is
}
```